# how to find unique records in a table. distinct shows one record from repeated. I want completely unique ie non repeated records

Tags: mysql

suppose i have the table student

roll     name
1         Nitin
2         Rohit
3         Nitin

then i want to find non repeated names. so it should return me only  rohit. got it. thank you waiting for the answer

Answer (score 0):

1) count the number of occurrences in the sub query t1 2) inner join to the sub query

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int,name varchar(10));
insert into t values (1,'nitin'),(2,'rohan'),(3,'nitin');

select t.*
from t
join
(
select t.name
from t 
group by t.name having count(*) = 1
) t1 on t1.name = t.name;

+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    2 | rohan |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```